# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo-server:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the backend of my project using docker but I'm getting this weird mongo network error and I just can't figure out why I'm getting this error. When I use the command docker-compose up, it gives me this error and because of that I can't even test localhost:3001.

Please help me solve this error. I can provide additional details if needed. I also looked at questions asked previously and tried all those solutions but nothing seems to help.

[image]

Here's my docker-compose.yml file. I've removed some important details but you can assume they are all there.

[image]

Comment: Add your docker-compose.yml file as well, seems container network not configured properly.

Comment: @v1shva I added it.

Comment: Check the logs of mongo container, maybe mongo db service is not running. First run `docker-compose up -d`, then `docker logs [container-id]`